# MT3608 wrong output voltage

Tags: layout, semiconductors, switching-regulator

I designed a 24V boost converter circuit using a input voltage of 5V shown below:

[image]

After producing the PCB for this, I tested the output voltage and found that the output voltage was at 5V instead of the intended 24V.

I had previous experience with this boost converter chip and know that it is capable of providing up to 24 Volts, therefore I am pretty certain that my PCB design was poor.

Would greatly appreciate it if somebody could point out the problem in the schematic/PCB, thanks!

PCB:

[image]

[image]

Link to datasheets of boost converter and inductor:

https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108131530_SXN-Shun-Xiang-Nuo-Elec-SMNR4020-22UH_C135264.pdf

Comment: Which one of the pictures above is flipped? How is the chip actually mounted on PCB? Have you checked resistance values?

Comment: As the components are mounted on the bottom of the PCB, the bottom most picture is flipped. Resistance values are fine.

Comment: Is the ground plane connected between left and right side of PCB?

Comment: Yes, though it is not shown in the pictures above.

Comment: Do you have more than 2 layers? As @Justme mentioned, Chip pin 2 and R6 look like an isolated island. A perfect explanation for the flat 5V output.

Comment: @Jens It's a 2 layer board. But do you mind explaining why that would result in a flat 5V?

Comment: As I understood your 2nd sentence, the IC is not switching at all and the 5 V input directly goes to the output via L1 and D1. With "flat" I intended to say "no switching". Seeing 5.0 V at the output is only possible if there is no current through R5 R6, which is only possible if IC pin 2 and R6 are not connected to GND. If they were, you would measure something like 4.7 V at the output (Vin - Vfwd (D1)).

Comment: @Jens Thanks for your explanation, will attempt to re-measure as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check D1 reverse recovery time
2. make the 5 V bus as robust as possible, a plane preferrably
3. Check the ground return path. Add GND plane on top side.
4. Move L1 on the right hand side of U1, so that it doesn't draw power from between the bypass cap and U1
5. Add a ~100 nF and ~1 uF bypass caps for U1. Put them as close as possible to U1 starting from the lowest value cap. Bypass cap placement in high frequency switching regulators can be critical

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, especially for points 4 and 5.